# C++ Using array and for loop to output from multiple classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop

I am asked to do this code and i need to use array or something similar to print out different classes. The only way i know is individually doing every single class is there a faster way of doing this. Following is the way i am using at the moment.

```
Ground_Transport Gobj;
Air_Transport Aobj;
Sea_Transport Sobj;
Car Cobj;
Train Tobj;
Bus Bobj;


Gobj.estimate_time();
Gobj.estimate_cost();
cout << Gobj.getName() << endl;

Bobj.estimate_time();
Bobj.estimate_cost();
cout << Bobj.getName() << endl;

Sobj.estimate_time();
Sobj.estimate_cost();
cout<<Sobj.getName()<<endl;

Aobj.estimate_time();
Aobj.estimate_cost();
cout << Aobj.getName() << endl;

Cobj.estimate_time();
Cobj.estimate_cost();
cout << Cobj.getName() << endl;

Tobj.estimate_time();
Tobj.estimate_cost();
cout << Tobj.getName() << endl;

Transport_KL_Penang Kobj;
cout << Kobj.getName() << endl;
```

This is the header file Transport_KL_Penang

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Transport_KL_Penang
{
public:
Transport_KL_Penang() {}
virtual string getName() {
    return Name;    
}

int Time_in_hours1 ;
int Time_in_hours2 ;
int Cost_in_RM1 ;
int Cost_in_RM2 ;
void estimate_time() ;
void estimate_cost() ;

 private:
 static string Name;
 };

 void Transport_KL_Penang::estimate_time() 
 {
cout << "It takes " << Time_in_hours1 << "-" << Time_in_hours2 <<
    " hours if you use " << Name << endl;
 }

 void Transport_KL_Penang::estimate_cost() 
{
cout << "It will cost around " << Cost_in_RM1 << "-" << Cost_in_RM2 <<
    "RM if you use " << Name << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130276/discussion-on-question-by-hammad-saeed-c-using-array-and-for-loop-to-output-fr).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a specific object name, you can write something as a code below, creating a multiples generics objects:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

class Myclass { 
private:
    int randTime; 
    float cost;
public: 
    void estimate_time(){
        randTime = rand()%100; 
    } 
    void estimate_cost(){
        cost = randTime * 0.2;
    } 
    float getEstimateCost(){
        return cost;
    }
}; 

int main(){ 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numberOfObjects = 7;
    Myclass obj[numberOfObjects]; 

    //input
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++){ 
            obj[i].estimate_time();  
            obj[i].estimate_cost();
    }
    // printing 
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++){   
          std::cout << obj[i].getEstimateCost() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```